# Attempting to save user input via HTML form and then refer back to it later

Tags: php, html

I am currently in the process of designing a Computer Aided Learning package. The welcome screen simply requires the user to type in their name into a text field and click a button which directs them to 'subject selection' page. How would I go about storing the user input and how, if possible, could I refer to the stored value on a seperate html page?

```
<div id="inputbox">
  <form>
     <input type="text" name="field" class="textInput" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="introsubmit">
    <a href="newgame.html" title="New Game" id="introsubmit"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML:**

```
<div id="inputbox">
  <form action="script.php">
     <input type="text" name="field" class="textInput" />
  </form>
</div>
<div id="introsubmit">
    <a href="newgame.html" title="New Game" id="introsubmit"></a>
</div>
```

That will send the form to script.php (if no 'action' defined, it will send the form to the very same page, if that html is inside `script.php` then it will work the same, and if no "method" is defined, if will use GET, you can set `<form action="script.php" method="POST">` to change this):

**script.php:**

```
<?php
session_start();

$_SESSION['name'] = $_GET['name'];
?>
```

and then you reuse that variable in the same session, remember to always invoke `session_start()` before any output in your `php`.

Comment: That won't work, the form has no action and even if it was the same file it will use `post` not `get` as the method.

Comment: 1. I'll clear that part. 2.Nope, `get` is the default. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.3

Comment: Touché, I must always just write `method="post"` without even realising.

Comment: I'm too lazy to write `method="get"` ^_^